# A python coded "alert"-like dialog or template

Tags: python, html, alert

**update 0:**
There is a subtle, but serious, error in my code and in my explanation below because I cannot only compare the `name` on the template with the `hiddenname` on the template (that much only tells me that the user has made a change like a checkbox change would tell me, but purposely there are no checkboxes), I also need to compare `name` to the status of `name` in the datastore of reservations to see if someone else has already reserved the time slot. So I cannot use javascript and I have to rewrite some of the code below to make the correct comparison, too. And may original question remains as suggested by the Title of this question. (In one of the comments I erroneously said that javascript would work.)
**update 0:**

I am trying to write a sort of "alert" in the way that this code suggests where I use the `Trans` model and the gae datastore (further below) to communicate between my main app and the "alert template". I have a few problems.

Initially I had my need for this alert in an another part of my code in an `else:` clause, not in an `elif:` clause. When I tried to use the simpler version of my alert in the `elif` code, python seemed to ignore the `self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))` and just went on to this code which ended my conditionals: `return webapp2.redirect("/read/%s" % location_id)`. So, as you can see in my code I have commented out the ignored former code line and attempted to replace it with something more like the latter code line, but with that latter line directed to `unexpected` instead of `read`. You can see from my code it is still a mix between the two approaches and I could use help sorting that out. Is there really something different about `else:` and `elif:` regarding this?

Originally I had not anticipated my desire to call the same html template and Trans model from so many places in my code, so I did not design a key or ID or key_name into the design of using `Trans`. And now I am having trouble implementing a version with such detail.

I have been looking for an example of how such "alert templates" can be made in python. They are so easy in javascript, but I am trying to do the user input validation in my python code. Any pointers to examples or docs would be greatly appreciated.

```
weekday_key = db.Key.from_path('Locations',location_id,'Courts', court_id,'Days',weekday)
if name == hiddenname:
    pass
elif name != hiddenname and hiddenname == "":
    reservation = Reservations.get_or_insert(time[2],parent=weekday_key) 
    reservation.hour = time[0]
    reservation.minute = time[1]
    reservation.year = int(year)
    reservation.nowmonth = int(nowmonth)
    reservation.day = int(day)
    reservation.nowweekday = int(nowweekday)
    reservation.name = name
    reservation.put()
elif name != hiddenname and name!="":
    reservation = Reservations.get_by_key_name(time[2],parent=weekday_key) 
    reservation.hour = time[0]
    reservation.minute = time[1]
    reservation.year = int(year)
    reservation.nowmonth = int(nowmonth)
    reservation.day = int(day)
    reservation.nowweekday = int(nowweekday)
    reservation.name = name
    reservation.put()
    reason='This was in that time slot already: '
    trans = Trans(parent=reservation.key().name()) #this line is iffy
    trans.reason=reason
    trans.name=hiddenname
    trans.put()
    iden = trans.key().id() # this is part of the iffy just above
    template_values = {'trans':trans}
    path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
    #self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
    return webapp2.redirect("/unexpected/%s/%d" % (time[2],iden) #more iffy
else:
    pass
```

My model for Trans in next.

```
class Trans(db.Model):
    reason = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
```

My jinja2 equipped `unexpected.html` template is as follows.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
This unexpected result occurred. {{ trans.reason }}:<emph style="font-weight: bold">{{ trans.name }}</emph>
<br /><br />
<div id="inputdata">
<label>Click the "Ok" button to go back to the previous page so you can elect to edit your entry, or not.
</label>
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Ok</button>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please do not use `<>`, use `!=` instead, from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#not-in): *"The <> spelling is considered obsolescent."* The `<>` operator has been removed altogether from Python 3.

Comment: why dont you use a normal javascript alert?

Comment: As I said in the question, "I am trying to do the user input validation in my python code." Isn't that inconsistent with using a javascript alert?

Comment: Nevermind. I think you are right. I have all the info I need in the template, and I should just use javascript. Thanks. So if I am just checking the difference between name and hidden name in my template, how do I do that in javascript? ` hiddenname != "" and name == ""`,`name != hiddenname and hiddenname == ""`,  ` name != hiddenname and name!=""` and then what?

Comment: No, I cannot use javascript because it cannot compare with the state of the reservations datastore if someone else has reserved while this user is making her choice.

Answer (score 0):

[This question is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565612/code-blows-through-html-template-and-returns-to-python-directly). It could have been answered in this question, but apparently there was too much information given and no one saw the answer.