# Code blows through html template and returns to python directly

Tags: python, html

[This question started as the question at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557733/if-conditionals-produce-html-302)

I think the problem is in the template `unexpected.html` (further below). The python code works fine, but when the user supplies a `number` and then clicks the submit button, the python code accepts the value and no matter which branch of the `if` clauses are taken, the resulting view in the browser is **both** the `unexpected.html` and the embedded html at the bottom of the python code.

Why doesn't the browser stop with just the `unexpected.html` template?

First below is the python code.

```
class MainPage(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    self.render_template('index.html', { })

    def post(self):
    number = self.request.get('number')
    hiddennumber = self.request.get('hiddennumber')
    for i in ["a"]:
        if int(number) < int(hiddennumber):
        reason='< was in that time slot already: '
        trans = Trans(key_name='reason')
        trans.reason=reason
        trans.name=number
        trans.put()
        template_values = {'trans':trans}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        elif int(number) > int(hiddennumber):
        reason='> was in that time slot already: '
        trans = Trans(key_name='reason')
        trans.reason=reason
        trans.name=number
        trans.put()
        template_values = {'trans':trans}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
        else:
        pass
    self.response.out.write('''
        <html>
          <body>
            <form method="post">
              <p>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
              <p>Favorite foods:</p>
              <select name="favorite_foods" multiple size="4">
                <option value="apples">Apples</option>
                <option value="bananas">Bananas</option>
                <option value="carrots">Carrots</option>
                <option value="durians">Durians</option>
              </select>
              <p>Birth year: <input type="text" name="birth_year" /></p>
              <p><input type="submit" /></p>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
        ''')

class Unexpected(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
        trans=Trans.get_by_key_name('reason')
        template_values = {'trans':trans}
        path = os.path.join(TEMPLATE_DIR, 'unexpected.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

    def post(self):
        day=self.request.get('day')
        return webapp2.redirect("/")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage), 
        ('/unexpected', Unexpected)
        ],
        debug=True)
```

The template `unexpected.html` is next.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}


<form action="" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="day" value="{{ day }}"/>
This unexpected result occurred: <emph style="font-weight: bold">{{ trans.reason }}</emph>
<br /><br />
<div id="inputdata">
<label>Click the "Ok" button to go back to the previous page so you can edit your entry.
</label>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</div>
</form>
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Ok</button>

{% endblock content %}
```

Finally, I am including `index.html` for greater completeness.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<center>
   </h1>
  </center>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hiddennumber"  value="10">
<label>Location/Venue name (no spaces and case counts)</label>
<input type="textbox" name="number" size="30" value=""></input><br/>
  <input type="submit" value=submit />
</form>


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere do you break out of the flow of execution that I can see, and the embedded HTML would be after the tests so there's no reason it wouldn't execute.  The fastest solution would just be to `return` when you're done:

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
return
...
```

In general you also have a lot of duplicated logic in that structure also: that should be consolidated and then the code could be further refactored to be more readable by making that structure more of just a dispatcher with the appropriate display logic in separate functions.